# Unable to update the Android system updates after installing Despair on Nexus 5

Tags: updates, nexus-5

I installed Despair kernel in Nexus 5 by following this [guide](http://wccftech.com/how-to-root-nexus-5-on-android-6-mra58k-marshmallow/). Then I installed Clockworkmod Recovery 6.0.4.5. I'm trying to update the system, but when I try to install, it brings me to Recovery and an error "Unable to verify signature" shown during install. The update does not get applied.

How do I resolve this update issue?

More information:

- Android OS: 6.0
- Android security patch level: 1 October 2015
- Baseband version: M8974A-2.0.50.2.27
- Kernel version: 3.4.0~Despair.M.HH.R1.9
- Build Number: MRA58K

Comment: Can you flash stock recovery and then try the update? Alternatively, disable signature verification in CWM (not sure it can be done, but TWRP and Philz Touch can) and then try with update.

Comment: CWM can disable signature verification, and I did it. But it is turned back on automatically when installing system patch. How can I find stock recovery and flash the recovery **only** ? I don't want to flash the whole OS